# How to append data on JavaScript?(React.js)

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, jsx

I want to append some JSON data to frontend(React.js)
After fetching the JSON data, I want to append the data to JSX.
The data looks like below:
(The value of description is string)

```
data = { description: "<p>Description Content</p><ul><li>list1</li><li>list2</li><li>list3</li<li>list4</li></ul>" }
```

I want to append this to JSX, how can I do that?

```
const Desctiption = ({ data }) => {
  const { description } = data;

  return (
    <div className="description-tag">

    </div>
  )
}
export default Desctiption;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const Desctiption = ({ data }) => {
  const { description } = data;

  return (
    <div className="description-tag">
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: description }} />
    </div>
  )
}
export default Desctiption;
```

However this approach might be risky. Check out the docs for more information:
https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml